# BLS API PHP file_get_contents no response

Tags: php

I'm getting an empty response from BLS for a request to their API.  Also, $http_response_header is empty.

Why would the $http_response_header be empty?  When trying via http instead of https, the response header at least shows the 301 redirect

```
$url = 'https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/';
$method = 'POST';
$query = array(
    'seriesid'  => array('CUSR0000SA0'),
    "registrationkey" => "XXXXXX" ,
    'startyear' => '2016',
    'endyear'   => '2018'

);
$pd = json_encode($query);
$contentType = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$contentLength = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($pd);
$result = file_get_contents(
    $url, null, stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => $contentType . "\r\n" . $contentLength . "\r\n",
            'content' => $pd ),
            "ssl"=>array(
                "cafile" => "C:/xampp/php/cacert.pem",
                "verify_peer"=> true,
                "verify_peer_name"=> true,
            ),
        )
    )
);
var_dump($http_response_header);
var_dump($result);
```

output:
    array(0) { } string(0) ""

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying curl instead and used the following to output the error.  The server was responding with an unknown SSL version because I am using an old version of PHP.  I upgraded my xampp and now I'm getting the expected results.

```
$fp = fopen('/errorlog.txt', 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```